# Hide AutoGenerateRows from a User Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, sqldatasource, auto-generate

I have a User Control with a DetailsView that has the property AutoGenerateRows set to 'true'.  My pages (asp.net and c# code), use a SQLDataSource for its data.  Typically I want all rows to show up in my WebForm, however, occasionally I want to be able to hide specific ones.  Is there any way to do this or do I have to hardcode every row I want and set autogeneraterows to false?

Help is appreciated!  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this After Binding

```
 foreach (DetailsViewRow Row in MyDetailsView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Your Condition..)
            {
                Row.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

you could do this for checking your value:

```
foreach (DetailsViewRow Row in MyDetailsView1.Rows)
            {
                if (Row.Cells[index of your column].Text=="")
                {
                    Row.Visible = false;
                }
            }
```

Comment: This is perfect.  However, the only condition I can find for Row would be the index position.  Is there any other property you can think of that would work to get maybe the text or something like that?

Comment: Problem. Any idea how to keep the field hidden when you go into edit mode?  All the once hidden fields remain while in this mode :(